# clarification to log-stock price formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

Having financial market with safe rate r and risky asset S with dynamics under physical measure P $$\frac{dS_t}{S_t}=\mu dt +\sigma dW_t$$ 
what is the log-stock price?

Using Ito formula it is straightforward to derive the below equation
$$log(S_T)=log(S_t) + (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t) + \sigma \ (W_T - W_t) \tag{1}$$

what should be equivalent to $$log(S_T)=log(S_t) + (r - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t) + \sigma \ (W_T^* - W_t^*)  \tag{2}$$

**Q 

what allows to formally transition (1) into (2)? 

I mean the change of dt into T-t and $\mu$ into r**

Comment: Should (1) be $\ln S_T = \ln S_t + (\mu-\sigma^2/2)(T-t) + \sigma (W_T-W_t)$? Similarly for (2).

Comment: I corrected the equations (1) and (2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dynamics 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} =\mu dt + \sigma dW_t.
\end{align*}
is under the real-world measure $\mathbb{P}$. Then,
\begin{align*}
d\ln S_t =\Big(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \Big) dt + \sigma dW_t.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\ln S_T = \ln S_t + \Big(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \Big)(T-t) + \sigma \big(W_T-W_t\big).\tag{1}
\end{align*}
To obtain the dynamics under the risk-neutral probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$, we employ the Radon-Nikodym derivative
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\big|_{\mathcal{F}_t} = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 t + \lambda W_t \right),
\end{align*} 
where $\lambda = (r-\mu)/\sigma$ is the market-risk premium. Then, from Girsanov theorem, the process $\{\widehat{W}_t, t \ge 0\}$, where
$$\widehat{W}_t = W_t -\lambda t,$$
is a standard Brownian motion under  measure $\mathbb{Q}$. Moreover, under  measure $\mathbb{Q}$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t} &=\mu dt + \sigma dW_t\\
&=rdt + \sigma d\widehat{W}_t.
\end{align*}
Consequently, similar to $(1)$ above,
\begin{align*}
\ln S_T = \ln S_t + \Big(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \Big)(T-t) + \sigma \left(\widehat{W}_T-\widehat{W}_t\right).\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Note that, in $(1)$ and $(2)$, the Brownian motions $W$ and $\widehat{W}$ are different.